# How to move data from specific rows from one column to the next?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

New to python and pandas. How do I get data from specific rows from one column to the next? I've attempted to use .shift, but can only get whole columns or rows to move up or down.

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
​
df = pd.DataFrame({'data1':['a','a','b','b','a'], 
                   'data2':['one','two','one','two','one'], 
                   'data3':['65168','65498.5','nan','nan','nan'], 
                   'data4':['3645','95324','0.35468','.36546','16567']})
df

Out[5]:
  data1 data2   data3   data4
0   a   one    65168    3645
1   a   two    65498.5  95324
2   b   one    nan      0.35468
3   b   two    nan      0.36546
4   a   one    nan      16567
```

Say I'd like to move data in rows 2,3,4, column 'data4' to rows 2,3,4, column 'data3' ONLY (.shift will move whole rows or whole columns as far as I can tell)

Desired result -

```
  data1 data2   data3   data4
0   a   one    65168    3645
1   a   two    65498.5  95324
2   b   one    0.35468  nan
3   b   two    0.36546  nan
4   a   one    16567    nan
```

The actual data will be read in from a previously generated .xlsx file. I just need to move data from specific indices from one column to another.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html#pandas.DataFrame.shift) column-wise by passing `axis=1`, `loc` with row-label selection and a column selection will ensure only those rows and columns are modified:

```
In [12]:

df.loc[2:,['data3','data4']] = df.loc[2:,['data3','data4']].shift(-1,axis=1)
df
Out[12]:
  data1 data2    data3  data4
0     a   one    65168   3645
1     a   two  65498.5  95324
2     b   one  0.35468    NaN
3     b   two   .36546    NaN
4     a   one    16567    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! I had seen examples of using .loc the ones I found werent returning what I needed. This does exactly what I wanted.